# Maven external dependency plugin skips resolve and install step

Tags: maven

I am using [Maven-external-dependency-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-external-dependency-plugin/), which worked by resolving and installing the dependencies properly till some time back. Now it is skipping the step shown below fully, although the path is valid and external file exists there. Running maven with the -X switch also did not show anything (the step was not executed at all). Can anybody who has used this plugin help out?

```
<execution>
<id>resolve-install-external-dependencies</id>
<phase>process-resources</phase>
<goals>
     <goal>resolve-external</goal>
     <goal>install-external</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
```

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: What is the packaging of the project that has this execution? What is the exact command you launch?

Comment: Hi, I use a multi-module Maven project in which parent module has packaging of POM and this external-dependency definition is in one of the child modules with WAR packaging. I launch the mvn clean install command from parent module. Hope this information is what you asked.

Comment: Given that, you should work. Can't you show a bit more of the WAR pom.xml?